# Как перенести последнее слово в каждой нечётной строке в начало файла?

Tags: linux, join, sed

Как можно перенести в каждой нечётной строке последнее слово в начало строки? Не через awk, а именно через sed/join/paste и прочие утилиты. На awk пробовал, там вроде всё легко, а вот с sed/etc не совсем понятно

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем-то получилось примерно так

```
cat text2.txt| sed "2~2d;s/\(^[А-Я][а-я ,.:;]\+\) \([а-я,.:]\+$\)/\2 \1/g" > replaced

cat text2.txt | sed "1~2d" > temp

paste -d"\n" replaced temp > main
```

Офк можно было без cat, но тут я начинал с того, что смотрел, как вообще выглядит сам файл.

Работает следующим образом: распечатываю файл, во всех чётных строках ищу 2 вхождения: первое - первая часть строки, не включая последнее слово, второе - последнее слово, далее делаю, грубо говоря реверс черех \2 \1 и вывожу всё в replaced. 2~2d позволяет вывести все нечётные строки.

Дальше я распечатываю все чётные строки и кладу в temp

После сцепляю их через paste

Answer (score 1):

```bash
sed -r -i '1~2s/(.*)[ \t]([^ \t]+)$/\2 \1/g' ./file
```

Меняем каждую нечетную строку в файле сразу с заменой:
`(.*)` - любое количество любых символов
`[ \t]` - пробел или символ табуляции
`([^ \t]+)` - любой символ кроме пробела или табуляции
`$` - символ конца строки

Для теста лучше убрать параметр `-i` что бы изменения выводились в stdout